# tablesorter v2.0 dynamically adding rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, tablesorter

We are trying to implement Tablesorter v2.0 in our solution. We are using Knockout, MVC, C# in our project.

We have scenarios throughout our project, where in a table, we are dynamically adding rows based on Search result conducted or adding/deleting a row.
We also implemented table sorting on above scenarios and they don’t seems to be working

**Scenario 1:**
1)  Added below line of code during page load
              $('.tablesorter').tablesorter();
2)  Added below line of code when dynamically adding/deleting a row in a table  or dynamically adding rows based on a Search result.
             $("table").trigger("updateAll"); or $("table").trigger("update");

**Scenario 2:**
1)  Added below line of code during page load
              $('.tablesorter').tablesorter();
2)  Added below line of code when dynamically adding/deleting a row in a table 
             $('.tablesorter').tablesorter();

**Issues in both scenarios:**
•   When we add a new row or dynamically adding rows based on Search results, based on point #2 (above), system is dynamically duplicating the rows in the table and also sorting is not happening correctly.

Any recommendations to resolve above problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tablesorter should only be initialized once. Using `$('.tablesorter').tablesorter();` more than once on the same elements will be ignored. Set the [`debug` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#debug) to test this behavior.

To update tablesorter's internal cache you should trigger an [`"update"` event](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#update).

1. Add new/remove rows.
2. `$("table").trigger("update");`

Only use the [`"updateAll"` event](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updateall) when adding or removing columns.

1. Add/remove a table column.
2. `$("table").trigger("updateAll");`